# python matplotlib blocks program control

Tags: matplotlib

I would expect the graph to display **first** but what happens is the mpl window pops up blank. It shows the points *after* the input line. ???

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
pl.ion()
pl.plot([1,2,3])
pl.show(block=False) #True doesn't do the job as well
raw_input() # time.sleep(3) demos the problem too
```

Why does this happen? How do I make it work as expected?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on python3.4 on Windows7

Comment: Me too, cannot reproduce this problem (python2.7, ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: What I want to happen is the graph to display and then the program control goes to the last line. I don't want to have to close the plot. Is this possible without using matplotlib interactive "GUI" elements?